# Compare 2 columns in different excel workbooks: Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to compare 2 Excel columns in different workbooks using Ppenpyxl in Python. So far what I've got is:

```
#Load the workbooks
wkb1 = load_workbook(filename = os.path.join(srcdir, "wbk1.xlsx"))
wkb2 = load_workbook(filename = os.path.join(srcdir, "wbk2.xlsx"))
#Find the last row of the excel data
ws1 = wkb1.active
wkb1_LastRow = ws1.max_row
ws2 = wkb2.active
wkb2_LastRow = ws2.max_row

for xrow in range (1,(wkb1_LastRow+1)):  
    for yrow in range (1,(wkb2_LastRow+1)):
        print (ws1.cell(row=xrow, column=1).value, ws2.cell(row=yrow, column=1).value )
        if ws1.cell(row=xrow, column=1).value == ws2.cell(row=yrow, column=1).value:
            print('HIT')
```

The thing is that the if statement always fails even though the 2 columns contain same values:

```
...
3145728 3145728,
3145728 3145729,
3145728 3145730,
3145728 3145731,
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems there is a whitespace in one value. Have you tried to use a trim?

Comment: You need to indent your `if` statement. Right now it's not part of the inner loop over `yrow`.

Comment: The indent mistake was made only in this post. This is not the problem

Comment: Trim did the thing, thx for catching it

Answer (score 0):

FWIW using nested loops is not the way to do this. It is much simpler to use `zip`.

The following should work:

```
for src, target in zip(ws1['A'], ws2['A']):
   if src.value == target.value:
       print("Hit")
```